# abrir url estando el navegador cerrado y que no se bloquee el botón en c++

Tags: c++, linux

Intento colaborar con el editor de Video Cinelerra GG que funciona en Linux, la persona que estaba a la cabeza del proyecto murió en un accidente de tráfico. Yo no se programación, muy poco, pero ahora estoy muy atascado con una tontería, se trata que desde el asistente de render por lotes quiero abrir una guía de inicio rápido. Use este código buscando por la red:

```
    //new help button
BatchRenderHelp::BatchRenderHelp(BatchRenderThread *thread, int x, int y)
 : BC_GenericButton(x, y, _("?"))
{
    this->thread = thread;
    set_tooltip(_("Open quick start guide"));
}

int BatchRenderHelp::handle_event()
{
    system("$CIN_BROWSER file://$CIN_DAT/doc/help_br_index.html");
    return 0;
}
```

y funciona muy bien, pero solo cuando el navegador web ya está abierto, el problema es que si el navegador esta cerrado, se abre al pulsar el botón "?" pero este botón queda bloqueado y junto con el toda el asistente, hasta que cierro el navegador.
¿hay alguna forma de solucionar esto?
Reconozco que no soy programador y hago esto por intentar colaborar, puesto que soy usuario de este editor gratuito, que es de lo mejor que tenemos en Linux.
MUCHAS GRACIAS POR ADELANTADO.

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo solucioné, en vez de usar la shell del propio programa para abrir el navegador en caso de que esté cerrado, he usado la opción xdg-open, y con esto se abre el navegador y queda liberada la shell. la linea a quedado así:

```
system("xdg-open file://$CIN_DAT/doc/help_br_index.html");
```

Y ahora funciona perfecto. Gracias a SatckOverflow por el espacio que nos ofrece.